# Edit tax calculation in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am working on an existing Magento 1.9 project.

Here is the scenario

In admin panel i have set the product price to 118, now in front end it showing the price to 100 + 18% tax, same in the checkout cart.

I just want to show 118 without any tax, how can i do that. Any guidance or pointing in direction will be a great help, this is my first php work..

Update to question Now i have update all tax rate to 0, but it is still reducing the prices as mentioned above, so i look at the My SQL table Sales_flate_quote, and it shows the price in column name subtotal-->495.76, base_subtotal--> 585, the price i set in magento is 585. i am still finding the possible cause.

On the index page, price is showing 585, when i go in cart it shows 495.76

Comment: did you get the solution ...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand your question, but are you aware of the tax display settings in the config (determining if the price should be shown including or excluding tax in frontend)?

[Screenshot of Magento System Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBIZd.png)

You can find these settings in System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax
There are settings for tax display type of product prices as well as cart prices.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention the calculation settings that are more likely what you are searching for:

[Screenshot of Tax Calculation Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMquT.png)

Especially have a look at "Catalog Prices" ("Whether catalog prices entered by admin include tax.")

You can find these settings in System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax too.